# How to read a matrix skipping N rows and M columns in Julia (with a windows eol)

Tags: io, julia

I need to read a tab separated 800MB matrix from Julia, where the first N rows and M columns are headers, and the file has a windows eol.

The database comes with the following matlab instruction:

```
A = dlmread('mydatafile.txt','\t',N,M);
```

It seems that `dlmread()` has been replaced in julia for `readdlm()` but I don't know how to specify the column offset nor the windows eof.

EDIT: corrected

Comment: What is C? Is it supposed to be M?

Answer (score 3):

After several tries, the best I could get with is to load the whole matrix, including column and row headers, slice it to remove the headers and convert to float the data:

```
table = convert(Array{Float64,2},readdlm("myFile.txt",'\t', skipstart=2)[:,4:end]);
```

This take ~51 seconds on a i7 laptop with an SSD disk for 873MB (7824x7824) matrix.

It's a pity that it is not possible to skip initial columns as well, as I believe it is a common situation and, by the way, it would also reduce differences with matlab scripts that use `dlmread()`.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [documentation](https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/stdlib/io-network/#Base.DataFmt.readdlm-Tuple%7BAny,Char,Type,Char%7D) of `readdlm` (which you get by `?readdlm`) you can use the keyword

- `delim` to specify the delimiter
- `eol` to specify the end of line character
- `skipstart` to specify how many initial rows should be ignored.

In total

`readdlm("mydatafile.txt", delim='\t', eol='\n', skipstart=N);`

I don't know how to ignore columns though.

Comment: I might have been hasty, maybe OP wants `eol="\r\n"` which won't work because it's a `String` not a `Char`.

Comment: I "managed" for smaller tables with `table = convert(Array{Float64,2},readdlm("myFile.txt",'\t', skipstart=2)[:,4:end]);` but I don't think it's going to be very efficient for big tables, as it is importing first everything as Any and only then slicing and converting.

Comment: Yes it won't be. If `readdlm` can't do it for you, you can parse the file line by line of course. A PR would also be welcome I guess.

Comment: @Antonello Maybe have a look at [CSV.jl](https://github.com/JuliaData/CSV.jl). It has an optional argument for specifying column types which should speed things up. From memory, Julia is still a little behind R in terms of raw speed when reading in large csv files, but it is improving daily, and I suspect you'll get the best speed using the above-mentioned package. Regarding ignoring columns, I don't think Julia has that capability yet. For now, I think you'll have to read all columns then ditch the ones you don't want.

Comment: @ColinTBowers Thank you, but CSV requires to know the header of the columns or their number (`header=3:end` doesn't work). Still, it saves to DataFrame, and for some reasons it is taking a lot of time and the resulting df behaves strangely (the "small" file has ~7000 cols).. I did also try using Matrix as stream, but it get stock forever. Hoverall, using `readdlm`, slicing and converting is the faster approach.

Comment: @Antonello It might not be a bad idea to post 5 or 10 rows of the csv file in question, and specify exactly what information the user has ahead of time, e.g. do they know number of columns, types in columns, etc. If you do this, then you might get a better optimized answer. I do know from numerous threads that Julia is still a little behind R in this, but we should be able to get close! :-)